# How to make a vertical tree in CSS using pseudo-elements

Tags: html, css, tree, pseudo-element

I'm trying to create a vertical tree in pure CSS using pseudo-elements :after and :before. I've got most parts working but if I have a sub-tree in the last item, the vertical bar is extended too.

I have been searching all over for a similar tree but most scripts out there are centered trees, I need one that works similar to a directory picker in windows. If you check the jsfiddle the problem will be quite obvious. http://jsfiddle.net/P76TQ/1/

I've already spent too many hours on this problem so I'm thankful for any help. If you have a suggestion of a better solution than mine, I'm all ears!

Levels are horizontal, items are vertical:

```
<div class="title">Question 1</div>
<div class="lv1 level">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="title">Item-1</div>
      <div class="lv2 level">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="title">Item-1-1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="title">Item-1-2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In a wonderfully ugly hack, you can cover things up with the background colour:

```css
.item:last-child::after {
    background-color: white;
    bottom: 0;
    content: '';
    left: -40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    width: 2px;
}
```

[At least it works!](http://jsfiddle.net/P76TQ/2/)

Comment: Thanks! I'm not a big fan of ugly hacks, but it's a start. I'm a bit concerned that it might prove a problem once I get to the styling part though. 

I'm trying to find out how this problem is solved here: http://jsfiddle.net/xxU7q/ but it's horizontal so it feels a bit like inception while trying to apply it in my case.